# How to connect docker port to jconsole

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, performance-testing, jconsole

We need to connect docker port with jconsole to monitor CUP utilization thread piling memory usage etc
We are using graphana to monitor response time

Any other application to monitor above requirement, can also suggest

We need to connect docker port with jconsole to monitor CUP utilization thread piling memory usage etc
We are using graphana to monitor response time

Any other application to monitor above requirement, can also suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use JConsole, all you need is to setup JMX agent inside your docker and then setup remote monitoring according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html). You can expose JMX agent port or just use port-forwarding. But I strongly don't recommend using this approach in production.

Probably best option for production will be to setup monitoring in your application, look at [micrometer-jvm-extras](https://github.com/mweirauch/micrometer-jvm-extras) for example